# Jasper report export as base64 string

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a code look as below:

```
                JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportsrc, Param, conn);
                JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, outputFile);
                exporter.exportReport();
```

which are working fine to output a pdf file to a physical folder. What I want  is to export the pdf as base64 string. Is there any way to do that?

thanks

Comment: You can use `exportReportToStream` to send the PDF to an OutputStream which performs Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by following code:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportsrc, Param, conn);
JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
exporter.exportReport();

byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
String pdfbase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(output);
System.out.println("pdf: "+pdfbase64 );
```